# Should email addresses be allowed in posts?

Tags: discussion

I recently saw [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/56639/8563) which (apart from being not very good and even slightly spammy) has an email address for further contact. I have seen this before in other posts and it's always made me squirm a bit. Is this sort of thing OK? Should I flag the posts for moderator attention? Should I edit the email out?

Comment: Well, that particular answer looks like outright spam to me, and containing an email address is the least of its problems.

Comment: Do you mean ThatGuy's answer? It isn't exactly spam, but somewhat...

Comment: @dimension10 The post in question has been deleted, see David Zaslavsky's comment to Manishearth's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address the more general issue of including email addresses in posts: this has come up several times on MSO, for example [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or), and also see the "Linked" section in the sidebar. The gist of those answers is that, although there's technically no rule against having an email address in a post, there is no good reason for it to be there.

So if you see an email address in a post, but the content of the post is otherwise worth keeping, I'd say

1. Edit it out
2. Flag the post for moderator attention so we can have the revision with the email address deleted from the revision history

There's some debate on MSO as to whether you should leave a comment suggesting to the OP that they shouldn't put sensitive information like email addresses in their posts. It could be argued that it draws attention to the email, but I don't think that's such a big issue on this site.

Of course, if the content of the post is not worth keeping, just treat it accordingly. Flag it for moderator attention, or as spam, if it looks like spam; and/or vote to close or delete it if you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 3):

While it's not disallowed per se,  you are well within your limits if you choose to remove it. (Flagging this was the right action--when in doubt, flag.)

Also, I highly doubt that that's mainstream physics (rather hard to tell, since I'm not entirely clear on what the user is trying to say -- and I haven't had time to read those links). If that is indeed the case, I (or another mod) can remove the post. For the time being I've added a `[citation needed]` post notice.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention!

Comment: I wound up deleting the post.